# apt: no such device or address

Tags: apt, filesystem

On Ubuntu 16.04, when I install any package, it says (for example):

```
# apt install links
... Selecting previously unselected package links.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to open files list file for package 'libtool': No such device or address
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I have never seen the `No such device or address` error from `apt`. Since a simply missing file would show `No such file or directory` I thought it might be caused by a recent computer crash: the disk had to have its bad block list rebuilt, though it now boots with no disk errors in `dmesg` and gets no errors from `fsck`.

Pursuing the "list file" complaint literally I followed advice in another thread: first did an `apt clean` (no effect on above error) and then tried deleting all the files in `/var/lib/apt/lists` & regenerating them with `apt update` (also no effect).  Trying to remove the `libtool` package also fails with the same error.

I am stuck without being able to find what the `No such device or address` error refers to.  If it does turn out to be a disk problem rather than an apt problem, at least if I knew the offending file it might be purged & recreated somehow.

Comment: What does this command do `sudo dpkg --remove libtool`?

Comment: dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: unable to open files list file for package 'libtool': No such device or address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [following](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1232143) steps.

1. Go into the /var/lib/dpkg directory
2. Make a backup of the "status" file
3. Edit the "status" file
4. Search the package that gave the error
5. Just delete the lines from this package (but let all other lines that concern other packages even if they contains the broken package in their "Replaces" or "Depends" fields)
6. Save changes in the "status" file
7. Run: 
   `sudo dpkg dpkg --configure -a`
8. Force the reinstallation of missing dependencies (because now, there are some) : 
   `sudo apt-get -f install`
   I think that if the broken package does not depend on any other package (could be rare), just reinstall it :
   `sudo apt-get install the_package`

Please let me know if it still fails.

Comment: thanks; it definitely started to work normally after I removed all lines (and only the lines) in the section beginning with `Package: libtool` from `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and ran `dpkg --configure -a`.  For step 8, since there were a couple of dependencies that I didn't want to adjust for, I just added the broken package (`libtool`) again instead.  That worked OK, as well as all package additions afterwards.